# How to deploy a Node js application on Windows?

Tags: node.js, deployment

I have a domain and hosting so I want to deploy nodejs in a Windows environment. However when I tried to find the best way to deploy it   they are all related to running nodejs in a linux environment. 
so how do I deploy it in a windows environment?

Answer (score 0):

When you map a domain name to an IP address, all traffic is going to come in on port 80 (http) & 443 (https), by default.

Here is a solution:

Suppose your domain name is `example.app.com` with its public IP address as `127.65.43.21:80`.

- Start your server on `localhost:8081`
- Add "local DNS" in the hosts file as a new line

  1. `127.65.43.21`        `example.app`
  2. Any free address in the network `127.0.0.0/8` `(127.x.x.x)` can be used.
  3. Assuming `127.65.43.21:80` is not occupied by another service.
  4. You can check with `netstat -a -n -p TCP` in powershell ran as Admin
- Add the following network configuration with netsh command utility:

  1. `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=127.65.43.21 connectport=8081 connectaddress=127.0.0.1`
- You can now access the server at `http://example.app.com`

You can **see the entry** you have added with the command:

`netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4`

You can **remove the entry** with the following command:

`netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=127.65.43.21`

Hope this answers your query.